# Uncaught InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and no url property; and no path property

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to load saved markers to the map from a database, which was working fine until now, I am getting the error in the console:

> Uncaught InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and no url property; and no path property

The code in question is:

```
$.get("event_data.php", function (data) {
        $(data).find("marker").each(function () {
              var name = $(this).attr('name');
              var description = '<p>'+ $(this).attr('description') +'</p>';
              var type = $(this).attr('category');
              var edate = $(this).attr('edate');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('lat')),parseFloat($(this).attr('lon')));
              create_marker(point, name, description, category, edate, false, false, false, "");
        });
    });

function create_marker(MapPos, eName, eForm, type, InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, Removable, iconPath)
{

    // Display the Icon by category
    switch(type){
        case 'meeting': iconPath = 'static/assets/meeting_marker1.png'; break;
        case 'clean' : iconPath = 'static/assets/clean_marker2.png'; break;
        case 'special' : iconPath = 'static/assets/special_marker.png'; break;
        case 'priority' : iconPath = 'static/assets/alert_marker.png';
    }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: MapPos,
        map: map,
        draggable:DragAble,
        title: eName,
        icon: iconPath
    });

......
}
```

The lines being highlighted in the console are:

> $(data).find("marker").each(function () {

and

> create_marker(point, name, description, category, edate, false, false,
>   false, "static/assets/new_event_marker.png");

and

> var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

Comment: Use `console.dir()` to dump out that object you're passing to `new google.maps.Marker`

Comment: Where should I put `console.dir()`

Comment: Right before that function call so you can see what's wrong with the object you're passing.

Comment: I ran `console.dir(create_event)` and It just returns the HTML script and the Javascript in the console. Should return some values??

Comment: I meant that you should log that object you're passing to `new google.maps.Marker()`.

Comment: OK.  See that call to `new google.maps.Marker()` in your code? Note that you're passing it an object. Use copy/paste to copy that object into a call to `console.dir()` that you add right before that call. That will show you exactly what is actually being passed, which should help a lot in figuring out what the Google code is complaining about.

Comment: [Your code as posted](http://jsfiddle.net/9tc5pcda/2/) works for me (fiddle based off the one I created for [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401125/google-maps-markers-from-database-displaying-information-from-the-last-row-onl))

Comment: One more time: pass to `console.dir()` the exact same stuff that you're **passing** to `new google.maps.Marker()`. The stuff that's in curly braces in the `( )` on the `new google.maps.Marker()` line.

Comment: Ok sorry.......that returns 1 object (which is the first item saved in the row), there are 3 items. Also, it returns `icon: false` so it is not getting the `iconPath`. But I dont see how, if it is working in the example code @geocodezip posted above.

Comment: @johnp91 well it looks like you're passing an extra parameter; if you line up the function call (the place you call "create_marker()") carefully match up the parameters you pass with the function, you'll see that one of those `false` parameters matches up with `iconPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. It was just a simple mistake. I had changed a parameter name (type) ,but never changed it in the output.

So This:

```
create_marker(point, name, description, category, edate, false, false, false, '');
```

became this:

```
create_marker(point, name, description, type, edate, false, false, false, '');
```